# How to search for an index of specific word with an index of specific character

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

Say for example I have the words below

```
THIS TEXT IS A SAMPLE TEXT
```

I am given character index 7.

Then I have to return index 1 when I split the sentence into words which is the index of the word that contains the index of character not 5 which matches the word that composes the index of character exactly but not the correct index where character lies.

basically I am trying to return the correct word index of where character lies (when split into words) with character index (when split with characters)

I thought I would reconstruct the word with something like below to find the word at the character

```
let curString = 'find a word from here';
let initialPositin = 5
let position = initialPositin

let stringBuilder = '';

while(position > -1 && curString.charAt(position) !== ' '){
  console.log('run 1')
  console.log(position);

  stringBuilder = curString.charAt(position) + stringBuilder;

  position --;
}

console.log(stringBuilder)

position = initialPositin + 1;

while(position < curString.length && curString.charAt(position) !== ' '){
  console.log('run 2')

  stringBuilder += curString.charAt(position);

  position ++;
}

console.log(stringBuilder);
```

Then split the sentence into words then find all the index of the word that contains the word that I have constructed. Then go through all the found words and reconstruct the previous words to see if the index of the target character in the reconstruction matches the character position given.

It doesn't really feel efficient. Does anyone have better suggestions?

I prefer javascript but I can try to translate any other language myself

Comment: "Then I have to return index 1 which is the index of the word that contains the index of character not 5 which matches the word that composes the index of character exactly but not the correct index where character lies." -> Sorry, you lost me there. Can you break this up into smaller parts and show with the help of examples?

Comment: @SaiBot Sorry. I meant I have to return index 1 when I split the sentence into words not 5 also when I split into words

Comment: @SaiBot basically I am trying to return the correct word index of where character lies (when split into words) with character index (when split with characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could just count spaces that occurs before given index, something like

```
let curString = 'find a word from here';
let givenIndex = 9;

let spaceIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < curString.length; i++) {
  if(curString.charAt(i) == ' ') {
      if (i < givenIndex) {
          spaceIndex++;
      } else {
          // found what we need
          console.log(spaceIndex);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could build a function that returns the position of all spaces.
Then you can see where the character index fits in that list of space positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "THIS TEXT IS A SAMPLE TEXT"
indexes = []
current_word = 0

for i in range(0, len(text)):

    if text[i] == ' ':
        current_word += 1  # After a ' ' character, we passed a word
    else:
        indexes.append(current_word)  # current character belongs to current word
```

You can build indexes array for once with this piece of code(written in Python3) then you can use it for every indice. If you want to count ' ' characters in indexes array as well, you can simple add them in for loop(in if statement).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using below code

```
let content = 'THIS IS A SAMPLE SENTENCE';
let target = 13;

let spaceCount = 0;
let index = 0;

while(index < target) {

    if (content.charAt(index) === ' ') {
        spaceCount++;
    }

    index++;
}

let splitContent = content.split(' ');
splitContent[spaceCount] = '#' + value
console.log(splitContent.join(' '))
```

Worked very nicely

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answer from @miradham this function counts the spaces before the given index, but with builtin functions to count character occurrences.

```js
function wordIndexOfCharacterIndexInString(index, string) {
  const stringUpToCharacter = string.slice(0, index)
  return (stringUpToCharacter.match(/ /g) || []).length
}

console.log(wordIndexOfCharacterIndexInString(7, "THIS TEXT IS A SAMPLE TEXT"))
```